# Webfont only working on frontpage in IE 7

Tags: javascript, fonts, embedded-fonts

The company I am working for bought a font at [myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com/). They included a javascript to make it working for different browsers.

The font is currently working in various browsers. Even in Internet Explorer partly. But it is not working with Internet Explorer on subpages different than the frontpage.

I already tried to contact the myfonts.com support. They said it has something to do with javascript errors on the subpages. But when I checked them no errors appeared at all. So I am not sure if it has something to do with that.

Comment: Could you post the relevant JavaScript that’s being used to make the fonts works in IE7?

Comment: I think that would maybe violate the terms and conditions of myfonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://blog.twostepmedia.co.uk/how-do-i-use-font-face-correctly-across-most-browsers/

Give this guide a try

Comment: This in combination with http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ saved my day. Too bad I couldn't find out what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

i hope this helps you

[make fonts wor in ie](http://symphony-of-dot-net.blogspot.com/2010/03/making-css-custom-font-works-with-ie.html)

but i suggest you to use google fonts. this is a common api compatible with all kind of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If it‘s working on the home page, but not other pages, maybe the JavaScript you’re using references the web font file (or some other file) with a relative URL that only works from the home page’s URL.

E.g. if your site’s URL structure is like this:

- / (Home page)

  - /products/
  - /services/
  - /about/
  - /font-files/
  - /javascript/

Then the JavaScript might reference the font file like this: `font-files/font.ttf`.

JavaScript URLs are relative to the HTML page that the JavaScript is running on, rather than the JavaScript file itself. You might want to change it to an absolute reference if you can, e.g. `/font-files/font.ttf`

Comment: I checked for wrong referencing in the javascript file, but didn't find any problems.